# MySQL select where variable is not in row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to do MySQL query to extract specific rows without the help of PHP if conditions,

okay,
i want to select a row where the variable is not in a specific row but here's the thing

```
$blocked_user = "aaron";
```

and in MySQL

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| id       | blocked               |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 1        | aaron,john            |
```

i want it to skip "aaron" while selecting and process to john

a false example :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $blocked_user NOT IN blocked
```

What i was doing is get blocked content and seperate them using php explode function then using in_array and if to confirm its not there :

```
if(in_array($blocked_user, explode($row['blocked'])){
  exit;
}
```

but now i want to get rid of this and do it using a single query, how is it done ?

Comment: Does your blocked field actually stores comma separated values?

Comment: imploded string in db field is not good idea. you should store each user in different row

Comment: @JorgeZapata nope, its actually a session username but just to show in example

Comment: @Osa - could you possibly add a full example in your question? I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you want - do you just want the 'John' part of the 'Aaron,John' string?

Comment: @user1538127 they could be over 1000 by time, i cant do that, i can in case there's any other idea to do the same thing but in a single row

Comment: What can the 'blocked' column contain? Do you need to find a substring match in it, or maybe it should begin with 'aaron', or maybe it is comma separated ...

Comment: @Osa - it's a lot easier to maintain 1000 records in individual rows than one string with 1000 entries in it. How do you remove an entry in the middle easily?

Comment: blocked column is a text column where all blocked users are added and each one is separated with comma, im trying to block aaron from selecting it using mysql query, i dont want to create multiple rows to seperate them

Comment: @andrewsi thats not possible because the row contains other info that is needed in other cases that cant also be repeated

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET to search for a value in a comma separated list. See @ZaneBien's answer.

Comment: @Osa - I'd suggest you read up on database normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really put each of the CSV values in different rows (perhaps in a `blocked` table), but what you can do is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$blocked_user', blocked) = 0
```

If the `$blocked_user` is contained within the CSV list in the `blocked` column, that row is not selected.

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a5e/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

There may be some sort of advanced regex MySQL you can do, but the problem is more deeply-set. Your table should really look more like this:

```
| id | blocked |
----------------
| 1  |  aaron  |
| 1  |   john  |
```

Where of course `id` is not of type primary key.

Then you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND blocked NOT IN ('aaron')
```

*As per your edit, if you have a second table, let's call it `data`*

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = 1 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM blocked_table WHERE blocked IN ('aaron'))
```

Comment: id 1 is a single row that i want to block specific people (aaron) from selecting it

Comment: So you have a separate table for that and you're linking them relationally, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but that requires that your blocked names be stored in separate rows.

Example:

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| id       | blocked               |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 1        | aaron                 |
| 2        | john                  |
```

Then you can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN on your users table like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN blocked as b
ON b.blocked = u.username
WHERE b.blocked IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE blocked NOT LIKE '%{$blocked_user}%'";
```